Linux cannot "find" DTB provided by QEMU
I'm trying to use QEMU 9 to emulate a Versatile AB development board and boot Linux.
I've grabbed vmlinuz and initrd.gz from the Debian Jessie netboot installer and the devicetree from contemporary Linux sources.
$ dtc -I dts -O dtb --out versatile-ab.dtb versatile-ab.dts
$ qemu-system-arm \                            
    -M versatileab \
    -nographic \
    -kernel vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-versatile \
    -initrd initrd.gz \
    -dtb versatile-ab.dtb \
    -append "console=ttyAMA0"

I briefly receive early console output but it warns that no DTB was "found", and then goes silent:
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
Warning: Neither atags nor dtb found

Why is Linux unable to find the DTB?

Using the monitor I can see that the DTB magic header at 0x4000000.
(qemu) xp /wx 0x0000000004000000
0000000004000000: 0xedfe0dd0

In QEMU sources, arm_setup_direct_kernel_boot() in hw/arm/boot.c puts the DTB address in FIXUP_ARGPTR_LO, which is loaded by the bootloader into r2 before execution passes to Linux. So this part is at least working.

If I omit the -dtb option it does boot, but one of my goals with this exercise is to play with the devicetree.
